# How to check if a 2D GameObject is touching something without OnTriggerEnter

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, collision-detection, collider

I want to avoid using OnTriggerEnter2D because I want to use it in a function like this:

```
void MyFunction()
{
    If (this.GameObject.IsTouchingSomething) {
        Debug.Log("I am touching somethin'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you actually want to do? You can call a function from OnTriggerEnter2D. Or using Physics2D.OverlapCircle. Or checking for bounding boxes. Depending on what you actually want to do, how many elements you need to check against, an answer closer to your need might appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to read the documentation. Any of these methods can do what you need:

- [Physics2D.OverlapCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCollider.html)
- [Collider2D.OverlapCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html)
- [Collider2D.IsTouchingLayers](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.IsTouchingLayers.html)

```cs
public class TouchDetector : MonoBehaviour {

    public LayerMask layersToCheck;

    public Collider2D collider;

    public void DetectTouch() {
        if (collider.IsTouchingLayers(layersToCheck)) {
             Debug.Log("I am touching something");      
        }
    }
}
```